# Google Search Query opens multiple tabs in Chrome

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

USing the below code works correctly, however if I use a search term like "Weather in Florida", it opens 5 tabs, all with the exact same search URL. The search URL looks like this "https://www.google.com/search?q=weather+in+florida", so it seems like it's getting passed correctly, I'm just not sure why multiple tabs are opening.

```
string searchTerm = textBox1.Text.Replace(" ", "+");
Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe",
      @"https://www.google.com/search?q=" + searchTerm);
```

If I try a longer query "what is the stock market like today in the united states" it opens 5 tabs again, so the tab count doesn't seem to be affected by the query length.

Anyone have any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working fine on my machine. You should check the extensions of Chrome.
Due to some extensions this problem may occurs.

Comment: Only extension I have is Adblock Plus.

Answer (score -1):

Ah, I found the problem. Was actually a loop that I was using, and the code was looping 5 times because I didn't have an if returning properly. It does work correctly, as  Chetan mentioned.

Comment: You should have tried to debug you code at least once.